# Get screenshots of all app that running in background (private API allowed)

Tags: ios, objective-c, background-application

When we press the button home twice, it will shows all app that running in background on screen.
Is there a way to get all these screenshot within app (with objective-c codes) ?

Comment: There is no public API for this. And it is a list of recently-used-apps, not background apps.

Comment: I'd call it a security problem if it was possible. A malicious app could use this to read users E-Mail or other personal information.

Comment: Probably Apple won't let you do that.

Comment: @downvoter : any reason for downvote? I don't think there is any reason for downvote...

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is **NO**.

***Why?***

Apple always maintain its own security. Apple never allow to access anything that could cause problem to any other app. Also apple don't allow to access its private API's.

Answer (score 1):

No, You can't do this. Apple doesn't provide any way that you write your own code and start interacting with other apps. According to me, it couldn't be possible.

If you find any solution to this, please let me know too.